# Serializing Dict Field inside List : ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am expanding JSON data from my [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75224041/data-does-not-get-saved-in-database-unexpected-keyword-arguments) question and trying to save it to the database. Period model contains `startDate` and `endDate` because the JSON object could have all 3, or maybe one of them so I want to make them options.

I am following steps given in the documentation for [Writable nested representation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) but I am unable to get the same results

Commented out code are the attempts I made to get the data to save.

When I am trying to save the data, I get

> ValueError: Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('instant', '2020-09-26')])":
> "Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents.period"
> must be a "Period" instance.

Models:

```
class Basetable(models.Model):
    basetable = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CompanyId = models.IntegerField()


class Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents(models.Model):
    cashtable = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True)
    unitRef = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    decimals = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    basetable_id = models.ForeignKey(Basetable, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Period(models.Model):
    period = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    instant = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, null=True)
    startDate = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255, null=True)
    endDate = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255, null=True)
    cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id = models.OneToOneField(
        Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Serializer:

```
class PeriodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # instant = serializers.DictField(
    #     child=serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255))
    # startDate = serializers.DictField(
    #     child=serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255))
    # endDate = serializers.DictField(
    #     child=serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255))
    instant = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)
    startDate = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)
    endDate = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=255)
    cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id = serializers.IntegerField(
        required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Period
        fields = "__all__"


class CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    period = PeriodSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents
        fields = ['decimals', 'unitRef', 'value', 'period']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        period_data = validated_data.pop('period')
        if period_data:
            period = Period.objects.create(**period_data)
            itemOne = Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents.objects.create(
                cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id=period, **period_data)
            return itemOne

    # def create(self, validated_data):
    #     print("validated_data", validated_data)
    #     instant = ''
    #     startDate = ''
    #     endDate = ''
    #     if (validated_data.get('period').get("instant")):
    #         instant = validated_data.get('period').get("instant")
    #     else:
    #         instant = None
    #     if (validated_data.get('period').get("startDate")):
    #         startDate = validated_data.get('period').get("startDate")
    #     else:
    #         startDate = None
    #     if (validated_data.get('period').get("endDate")):
    #         endDate = validated_data.get('period').get("endDate")
    #     else:
    #         endDate = None

    #     period = Period.objects.create(
    #         **{"instant": instant, "startDate": startDate, "endDate": endDate})
    #     itemOne = Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents.objects.create(
    #         cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id=period, **validated_data)
    #     return period


class CashFlowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents = CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsSerializer(
        many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Basetable
        fields = "__all__"
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        itemOneData = validated_data.pop(
            'CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents')
        cashflow = Basetable.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in itemOneData:
            Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents.objects.create(
                basetable_id=cashflow, **data)
        return cashflow
```

View:

```
def companyApiCall(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        jsonToUse = {
            "CompanyId": "320193",
            "CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents": [
                {
                    "decimals": "-6",
                    "unitRef": "usd",
                    "period": {
                        "instant": "2020-09-26"
                    },
                    "value": "39789000000"
                },
                {
                    "decimals": "-6",
                    "unitRef": "usd",
                    "period": {
                        "instant": "2019-09-28"
                    },
                    "value": "50224000000"
                },
                {
                    "decimals": "-6",
                    "unitRef": "usd",
                    "period": {
                        "instant": "2018-09-29"
                    },
                    "value": "25913000000"
                }
            ]
        }
        check = CashFlowSerializer(data=jsonToUse)
        if (check.is_valid(raise_exception=True)):
            print("ready to send to db")
            check.save()
        return JsonResponse(jsonToUse, safe=False)
```

Thank you for the time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `CashFlowSerializer`, try this (added in-line comments to explain the changes):

```py
class CashFlowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents = CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalentsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Basetable
        fields = "__all__"
        
    def create(self, validated_data):
        itemOneData = validated_data.pop('CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents')

        cashflow = Basetable.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for data in itemOneData:
            # Pop the period data because the long-named model 
            # is not happy with it and cannot process it
            period_data = data.pop("period") 

            my_long_named_obj = Cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents.objects.create(basetable_id=cashflow, **data)

            # Handle the period data and assign the newly created long-named model object
            my_period_object = Period.objects.create(
                cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id=my_long_named_obj,
                **period_data,
            )

        return cashflow
```

Comment: Brian, thank you for the reply. It makes sense on what you said but I am running into the following. We are passing what it is expecting to I am a little confused. Could I please ask for your help. 

`rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'CashCashEquivalentsRestrictedCashAndRestrictedCashEquivalents': [{'period': {'cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')]}}, {'period': {'cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id': ......`

Comment: From your question `cashcashequivalentsrestrictedcashandrestrictedcashequivalents_id` is optional, was that changed to required?